# Message.sendEmail not working

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm working on a test method to compare the picklists values.This is what I'm planning to implement..

```
Set<String> s1 = new Set<String>();//Holds picklist values of a field from Test1 object
Set<String> s2 = new Set<String>();//Holds picklist values of a field from Test2 object
```

I'm checking if the values in 's1' are in 's2'..if not populating them in a separate Set s3...

```
if(s3 != null){
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'test1234@gmail.com'};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setSubject('sai');
mail.setUseSignature(false);
mail.setPlainTextBody('body');
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}else{
System.assertEquals(s1.size(), s2.size());
}
```

Now my s3 is not null so it should enter into my if and send email...but I don't see any email being sent....not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: Unit tests cause no permanent change to the database, including sending emails.

Comment: Try using `if(s3.size()>0)` instead of comparing it to null.

Comment: Take a look at [SingleEmailMessage not working when used through apex test method](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160779/singleemailmessage-not-working-when-used-through-apex-test-method/160788#160788).

Comment: I ran into this issue before and the reason was that I was coding in a sandbox which had crossed the 'out bound email limits'  for that day. Next day, they ran just fine. This holds true especially when you are on Developer Edition org and orgs evaluating Salesforce during a trial period where the limits are low(just 15 mails per day)