# Test class for Email with Attachments

Tags: unit-test

I have written the following class and it functions properly. Unfortunately, I dont even know how to get started on writing the test class for this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the class:

```java
public class ServiceReassignmentButtonCtrl {
    private final Dealership__c dealer;
    private final String percentPremiumEmailTemplate = 'Percent_Prm_Reassign';
    private final String ServiceReassignmentTemplate = 'Service_Reassignment_Template';
    private final String FCAReassignmentTemplate = 'FCA_Reassignment_Template';
    private final String ReassignmentEmailTemplate   = 'Reassignment_Template';
    private final String AudiOptin = 'AudiOptInStandard';
    private final String AudiOptinPrem = 'AudiOptInPercentPrem';
    private final String BMWOptin = 'BMWOptInStandard';
    private final String BMWOptinPrem = 'BMWOptInPercentPrem';

    transient public Account VisualForceAccount{get; set;}

    public ServiceReassignmentButtonCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        this.dealer = (Dealership__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public Dealership__c getDealerInfo(String dealerID){
        Dealership__c dealerInfo = [SELECT OwnerId, Dealership_Spiff_Payment__c, Partner__c FROM Dealership__c WHERE Id=:dealerID LIMIT 1];
        return dealerInfo;
    }

    public List<Account> getClientList(String dealerID){
        List<Account> client = [SELECT Id, Participant_Name__c, Active__c FROM Account WHERE Dealership__c =:dealerID];

        return client;
    }
    //Sends email
    public void autoRun(){
        String dealershipId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

        Dealership__c dealerInfo = getDealerInfo(dealershipId);
        String templateType;
        String optinForm;

        if(dealerInfo.Dealership_Spiff_Payment__c == '% premium'){
            templateType = percentPremiumEmailTemplate;
        }else if(dealerInfo.Partner__c.contains('Service')){
            templateType = ServiceReassignmentTemplate;
        }else if(dealerInfo.Partner__c.contains('Jeep') || dealerInfo.Partner__c.contains('RAM') || dealerInfo.Partner__c.contains('Chrysler')|| dealerInfo.Partner__c.contains('Dodge')|| dealerInfo.Partner__c.contains('Alfa Romeo') ||dealerInfo.Partner__c.contains('Fiat')){
            templateType = FCAReassignmentTemplate;

        }else {
            templateType = ReassignmentEmailTemplate;
        }

        if (dealerInfo.Partner__c.contains('Audi')){
            optinForm = AudiOptin;  
        }else if(dealerInfo.Partner__c.contains('Audi') && dealerInfo.Dealership_Spiff_Payment__c == '% premium'){
            optinForm = AudiOptinPrem;
        }else if (dealerInfo.Partner__c.contains('BMW')){
            optinForm = BMWOptin;  
        }else (dealerInfo.Partner__c.contains('BMW') && dealerInfo.Dealership_Spiff_Payment__c == '% premium'){
            optinForm = BMWOptinPrem;
        }

        EmailTemplate template = [Select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName =:templateType LIMIT 1];

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 

        // Sets the paramaters of the email

        email.setTemplateId( template.id );
        email.setTargetObjectId(dealerInfo.OwnerId);
        email.setSaveAsActivity(false); // This is set as false while calling from apex
        email.setWhatId(dealershipId);

        List<Account> clientList = getClientList(dealershipId);

        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] attachmentList = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{};
        for(Account cl: clientList){
            if(cl.Active__c == 'Yes'){
                PageReference pdf = Page.attachmentPDF; 
                pdf.getParameters().put('id',cl.id);

                // Take the PDF content
                Blob b = pdf.getContent();

                // Create the email attachment
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                efa.setFileName(cl.Participant_Name__c + '- Confirmation Card.pdf');
                efa.setBody(b);
                attachmentList.add(efa);    
            }

         }
        if(optinForm!= null){
            StaticResource sr = [Select  s.Name, s.Id, s.Body From StaticResource s where s.Name =:optinForm];

            Blob tempBlob = sr.Body;
            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment opt = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            opt.setBody(tempBlob);
            opt.setFileName('Opt-in.pdf');
            attachmentList.add(opt);
        }


        email.setFileAttachments(attachmentList);

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] emailList = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email};
        Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);

    }
}
```

Here is a shot at writing test class by googling but like I said it doesnt work and I have no clue what I am doing:

```java
@isTest
public class ServiceReassignmentButtonCtrl_Test {
    public static ServiceReassignmentButtonCtrl controller;
    static Account parentC;
    static Account client1;
    static Account client2;

    static testMethod void myCommonMethod() { 
        TestDataUtils.triggerSwitchSetup();

        Dealership__c deal = new Dealership__c(Dealership_State__c = 'IN',Partner__c = 'BMW', Dealership_Spiff_Payment__c = '30');
        insert deal; 

        List<Account> listAcc = new List<account>();
        client1 = TestDataUtils.createAccountFromRecordType(Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Referral Program - Participant Form').getRecordTypeId());
        client1.Dealership__c = deal.ID;
        client1.Dealership_Partner__c = 'BMW';
        client1.Dealership_State__c='IN';
        client1.Name = 'Parent Name';
        client1.Participant_Name__c = 'Afzaal';
        client1.Active__c = 'Yes';
        client1.Client_Number__c = '12345.0';
        //Account client1 = new Account(Dealership__c = deal.ID, Dealership_Partner__c = 'BMW', Client_Number__c = '12345', Participant_Name__c = 'Afzaal', Active__c='Yes');
        listAcc.add(client1);

        client2 = TestDataUtils.createAccountFromRecordType(Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Referral Program - Participant Form').getRecordTypeId());
        client2.Dealership__c = deal.ID;
        client2.Dealership_Partner__c = 'BMW';
        client2.Dealership_State__c='IN';
        client2.Name = 'Parent Name2';
        client2.Participant_Name__c = 'Zanna';
        client2.Active__c = 'Yes';
        client2.Client_Number__c = '12346.0';
        //Account client2 = new Account(Dealership__c = deal.ID, Dealership_Partner__c = 'BMW', Client_Number__c = '12346', Participant_Name__c = 'Zanna', Active__c='Yes');
        listAcc.add(client2);

        insert listAcc;

        Test.startTest();
        PageReference pageRef = Page.ServiceReassignmentButton;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        pageRef.getParameters().put('id',deal.Id);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(deal);

        ServiceReassignmentButtonCtrl controller = new ServiceReassignmentButtonCtrl(sc);
        controller.autoRun();

        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: [Get Started with Apex Unit Tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro)?
[Testing Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm)?

Comment: I have written several test classes before. I think my confusion here is what do I do with a class that sends emails and attachments? How do I test that? What would by system.assert statements look like? Very lost and confused for some reason

Comment: I hope my answer on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160779/singleemailmessage-not-working-when-used-through-apex-test-method/160788#160788) post helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about what you are building in the email(s), you need two methods. One which does all the construction, and another to do the sending. Basically:

```
public static List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> buildEmails(/*inputs*/)
{
    // implementation
}
public static void sendEmails(/*inputs*/)
{
    Messaging.sendEmail(buildEmails(/*inputs*/));
}
```

In this way, you can test that the emails are being sent, but also what they contain. Most of your test complexity would then be able to focus on the `buildEmails` method and checking that the output conforms to desired behavior. When testing `sendEmails`, you just need to assert against `Limits.getEmailInvocations()`.